# DataTables: issue with adding rows after Ajax request

Tags: jquery, datatables

When I add the data from server to data table with following line,

```
allOrder.rows.add(response.orderList).draw();
```

I get a warning

> DataTables warning: table id={id} - Requested unknown parameter 0 for row 0

My table initialization:

```
ele.DataTable({
   "retrieve": true,
   "responsive": false,
   "columns": [
      {"data": "eOrderNo"},
      {"data": "siebelOrderNo"},
      {"data": "networkId"},
      {"data": "serviceId"},
      {"data": "customerName"},
      {"data": "orderRef"},
      {"data": "ocn"},
      {"data": "originator"},
      {"data": "custService"},
      {"data": "status"},
      {"data": "orderType"},
      {"data": "productDetails"},
      {"data": "createDate"},
      {"data": "csd"},
      {"data": "crd"},
      {"data": "icd"},
      {"data": "cpd"},
      {"data": "ActualDate"}
   ],
   "scrollY": "300px",
   "scrollCollapse": true,
   "sScrollX": "100%",
   "sScrollXInner": "400%",
   "paging": true,
   "pageLength": 25,
   "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
   "pagingType": "simple",

   /* for V Scroll */

   "bFilter": false,
   "bInfo": true,
   "bProcessing": true,
   "order": [
      [10, "desc"]
   ],
   "autoWidth": false,
});
```

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000050002",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000050002",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "",
        "customerName": "PIPPO",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "BREZZOLARI",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Migrated to OH&P",
        "orderType": "New Order",
        "productDetails": " Voice Connect",
        "createDate": "2000-04-27 20:40:17.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-05-03 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-10-18 17:52:55.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000083855",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000083855",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "LON/LON/E1D24282,\nLON/LON/E1D24284, \nLON/LON/E1D24285  (Ceased)",
        "customerName": "PAINE WEBBER",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "SHARRON GANDER",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Cease",
        "productDetails": "Customer Related Services",
        "createDate": "2002-02-07 13:57:12.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "2001-12-14 00:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2002-03-07 00:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2002-03-07 00:00:00.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000084305",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000084305",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "",
        "customerName": "PAINE WEBBER",
        "orderRef": "MC600",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "PAUL BURTON",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Cease",
        "productDetails": " Link Metro",
        "createDate": "2001-04-17 09:11:03.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "2001-04-14 00:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2001-05-17 00:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2001-05-03 00:00:00.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000084799",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000084799",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "LON/LON/LE-100779  (ceased)",
        "customerName": "INVESTEC",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "22593",
        "originator": "",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Cease",
        "productDetails": " LANLink Metro",
        "createDate": "2002-11-21 16:48:36.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "2002-11-21 00:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2003-01-06 06:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2002-11-29 00:00:00.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000088037",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000088037",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "LON/LON/E1-027579",
        "customerName": "EVOLUTION CONSULTING GROUP",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "STUART HORINE",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Modification",
        "productDetails": " Voice Line",
        "createDate": "2001-01-22 11:06:21.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2001-02-12 00:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2001-01-22 00:00:00.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100001",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100001",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "DLEI00003",
        "customerName": "ECOMP ENGINEERING GMBH",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "HERR WELLER",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Closed",
        "orderType": "New Order",
        "productDetails": " LANLink Metro",
        "createDate": "2000-01-03 09:18:32.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "2000-01-14 23:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-01-14 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-01-13 16:31:38.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100001/1",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100001/1",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "DLEI00003",
        "customerName": "NEXTRA DEUTSCHLAND COMMUNICATION GMBH",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "OMN01",
        "originator": "HERR RUDOLF MORBITZER",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Cease",
        "productDetails": " LANLink Metro",
        "createDate": "2001-02-23 09:22:20.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "2001-03-30 23:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2001-04-01 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2001-04-02 16:19:56.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100002",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100002",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "SE0100135-142",
        "customerName": " TELECOM STUTTGART",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "LUDWIG MODRA",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Internal",
        "productDetails": " Link Metro",
        "createDate": "2000-01-03 09:10:34.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-01-11 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-01-13 06:55:10.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100003",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100003",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "HE0X01125",
        "customerName": "MEDIA CONSULTING JOERG MANDT",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "HERR JOERG MANDT",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Closed",
        "orderType": "New Order",
        "productDetails": " Voice Line",
        "createDate": "2000-01-03 09:18:36.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-01-16 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-08-13 23:00:00.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100003/1",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100003/1",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "HE0X01125",
        "customerName": "MEDIA CONSULTING JOERG MANDT",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "HERR JOERG MANDT",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Cease",
        "productDetails": " Voice Line",
        "createDate": "2000-08-03 12:16:25.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "2000-08-03 23:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-08-15 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-08-13 23:00:00.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100004",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100004",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "FE1V11746",
        "customerName": " TELECOM FRANKFURT",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "HERR SANDRO INGLESE",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Internal",
        "productDetails": " Link Metro",
        "createDate": "2000-01-03 09:22:23.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-01-23 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-02-02 12:53:57.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100005",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100005",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "FE1S11747",
        "customerName": " TELECOM FRANKFURT",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "HERR SANDRO INGLESE",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Internal",
        "productDetails": " Link Metro",
        "createDate": "2000-01-03 09:26:12.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-01-23 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-01-20 07:27:36.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100006",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100006",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "HE0X01126.",
        "customerName": "MEDIA CONSULTING JOERG MANDT",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "HERR JOERG MANDT",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Closed",
        "orderType": "New Order",
        "productDetails": " Voice Line",
        "createDate": "2000-01-03 09:38:33.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-01-16 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-08-13 23:00:00.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100006/1",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100006/1",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "HE0X01126",
        "customerName": "MEDIA CONSULTING JOERG MANDT",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "HERR JOERG MANDT",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Cease",
        "productDetails": " Voice Line",
        "createDate": "2000-08-03 12:20:49.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "2000-08-03 23:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-08-15 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-08-13 23:00:00.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100007",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100007",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "FE5RI0529",
        "customerName": " TELECOM FRANKFURT",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "HERR OLIVER GROSS",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "New Order",
        "productDetails": "INTERNAL",
        "createDate": "2000-01-03 09:34:31.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-02-20 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-02-21 07:36:34.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100008",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100008",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "NA",
        "customerName": " TELECOM FRANKFURT",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "HERR BRIAN CALLAN",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Internal",
        "productDetails": "INTERNAL",
        "createDate": "2000-01-03 09:41:09.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "2000-01-30 23:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-01-31 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-02-22 17:10:27.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100009",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100009",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "F_IA00053",
        "customerName": " TELECOM FRANKFURT",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "HERR JENS MOELLER",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Internal",
        "productDetails": "Others (PW)",
        "createDate": "2000-01-03 09:46:59.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-01-25 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-01-20 14:30:23.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100011",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100011",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "FE1X11748",
        "customerName": "AZYX DEUTSCHLAND GMBH",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "HERR HERRWIG",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Closed",
        "orderType": "New Order",
        "productDetails": " Voice Line",
        "createDate": "2000-01-03 10:50:19.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "2000-01-21 23:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-02-10 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-02-11 13:01:59.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100011/1",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100011/1",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "FE1X11748",
        "customerName": "AZYX",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "AZY01",
        "originator": "TBA",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Cease",
        "productDetails": " Voice Line",
        "createDate": "2003-04-30 11:16:33.0",
        "csd": "2003-04-29 23:00:00.0",
        "crd": "2003-04-29 23:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2003-05-01 07:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2003-05-13 14:40:52.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100013",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100013",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "FE1P11864",
        "customerName": "CARPENET INFORMATION TECHNOLOGIES GMBH",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "HERR DAVIS",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Closed",
        "orderType": "New Order",
        "productDetails": " Link Metro",
        "createDate": "2000-01-03 10:48:03.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "1999-12-31 23:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-02-20 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-02-21 13:28:33.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100013/1",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100013/1",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "FE1P11864",
        "customerName": "CARRIER1 GMBH & CO. KG",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "CAR01",
        "originator": "FRAU BRIGITTE DAVIS",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Cease, All",
        "productDetails": " Link Metro",
        "createDate": "2004-12-06 14:29:00.0",
        "csd": "2004-11-28 23:00:00.0",
        "crd": "2004-12-31 16:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2005-01-03 11:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2005-02-03 14:56:54.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100013SH1",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100013SH1",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "96W/89002/89002/10421, DA: 11;\n96W/89002/89002/12220; DA72;",
        "customerName": "NEUBO HAUSVERWALTUNG GMBH & CO. BETRIEBS KG",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "517322",
        "originator": "HERR HELMUT SCHLACHTER",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Closed",
        "orderType": "Upgrade",
        "productDetails": " Voice Line",
        "createDate": "2002-07-05 10:40:02.0",
        "csd": "2002-07-03 23:00:00.0",
        "crd": "",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2002-08-12 07:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2002-08-12 11:21:38.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100013SH1/1",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100013SH1/1",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "96W/89002/89002/10421, DA11;\n96W/89002/89002/12220; DA72;",
        "customerName": "NEUBO HAUSVERWALTUNG GMBH & CO. BETRIEBS KG",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "517322",
        "originator": "HERR HELMUT SCHLACHTER",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Closed",
        "orderType": "Modification",
        "productDetails": " Voice Line",
        "createDate": "2002-08-05 15:55:25.0",
        "csd": "2002-08-04 23:00:00.0",
        "crd": "",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2002-08-25 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2002-08-26 09:45:04.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100013SH1/2",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100013SH1/2",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "96W/89002/89002/10421, DA11;\n96W/89002/89002/12220; DA72;",
        "customerName": "NEUBO HAUSVERWALTUNG GMBH & CO. BETRIEBS KG",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "517322",
        "originator": "HERR HELMUT SCHLACHTER",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Cease, All",
        "productDetails": " Voice Line",
        "createDate": "2004-10-11 10:43:06.0",
        "csd": "2004-10-03 23:00:00.0",
        "crd": "",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2004-10-11 11:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2004-10-11 10:45:12.0"
    },
    {
        "eOrderNo": "000100014",
        "siebelOrderNo": "000100014",
        "networkId": "",
        "serviceId": "N/A",
        "customerName": " TELECOM GMBH",
        "orderRef": "",
        "ocn": "",
        "originator": "THORSTEN KULKE",
        "custService": "",
        "status": "Completed",
        "orderType": "Internal",
        "productDetails": "Others (PW)",
        "createDate": "2000-01-03 10:56:10.0",
        "csd": "",
        "crd": "2000-02-03 23:00:00.0",
        "icd": "",
        "cpd": "2000-04-13 23:00:00.0",
        "ActualDate": "2000-04-13 10:59:08.0"
    }
]
```

The rows are drawn on the table but there is no data that is added to the table.

My table header is as follow:

```
<table id="allOrders" class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">eOrderNo</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">siebelOrderNo</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">networkId</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">serviceId</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">customerName</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">orderRef</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">ocn</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">originator</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">custService</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">status</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">orderType</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">productDetails</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">createDate</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">csd</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">crd</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">icd</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">cpd</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="title description goes here..">coltActualDate</th>
</thead>
</table>
```

> FINAL EDIT: My issue was the placement of code that populated the
>   table. It was in a different scope than the scope where the code of
>   table initialization was placed, hence it was conflicting with the
>   original initialization.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: @JSantosh i am using live load of data from an internal server. which i wont be able to replicate on fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4 .
In your case part "Diagnosis/Parameter is an integer" is relevant:

> When {parameter} is an integer, DataTables is looking for data from an array. This is usually the case when using DOM sourced data (i.e. the data for the table is read automatically from the document). In this circumstance the requested data doesn't exist in source array - likely because the array isn't long enough. This can occur if:
>
> - There is a colspan or rowspan in the tbody of the table, which is not supported by DataTables.
> - Using columns or columnDefs you have specified more columns than there are in the HTML
> - The number of cells in the table does not satisfy the equation #cells = #columns * #rows (i.e. there are more columns defined in the header than in the table body, or vice-versa).

There is no `<tbody>` tag in your html code, so add it is as described in linked documentation.

**UPDATE**

Also check this: in column definitions you have `{"data": "coltActualDate"}` and in JSON array you have `"ActualDate": "2000-10-18 17:52:55.0"` . Probably it does not work because names does not match.

**UPDATE 2**

I have created JSfiddle with your code, everything is working correctly.
https://jsfiddle.net/uosa3dha/1/

Comment: I have already read the document, and checked the three points

i just added <tbody> tag aswell, still its the same error.

Comment: So check names as I added in update, all other names match, only last one is different in column definitions and in JSON array of objects.

Comment: i have updated the question , i had to remove my company name from the json and html. the coltactualdate is correct. and present in both json and my columns

Comment: The fiddle did help me out in a way, 
my init code and rows.add code were on different js scopes, once i made changes to the page and loaded the data from same JS scope, its working as expected. Basically i moved the button click on the same document.ready where my table init code was.

Answer (score 1):

> **SOLUTION**

Add [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) and set it to empty string (`''`) to match your data structure as shown below:

```
ele.DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: 'script.php',
        dataSrc: '' 
    },
    /* ... skipped ... */
});
```

From the [`ajax.dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option description:

> Note that if your Ajax source simply returns an array of data to
>   display, rather than an object, set this parameter to be an empty
>   string.

> **NOTES**

There are other issues with your code

- Trailing comma after `"autoWidth": false`
- `thead` element must have `tr` tag inside, wrap `th` in `tr`.

Comment: thanks for the response, but for my case, the data needs to populated AFTER a user action, and not when the datatable is loaded into page. 
Also <tr> wrap was removed for a hit and trial, just to see if there is some issue with access to th by jquery.

also as per JSON specification the array can have a trailing comma, but thanks for pointing it out, and i have corrected it in my actual code.

Comment: And special thanks for editing the code, which i should have done.